# Android androidx.recyclerview remove Scroll Effect

Tags: android-recyclerview, scroll, androidx

I've just migrated the code base to Androidx and found that all the recyclerViews have their Scroll Effect showing again.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:clipToPadding="false"
               android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
               android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
               android:overScrollMode="never"
               android:paddingTop="32dp"
               android:paddingBottom="32dp"
               app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
               tools:itemCount="9"
               tools:listitem="@layout/item_section_other" />
```

Before androidx I removed the scroll effect adding

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

but it seems that's not working anymore.
Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: Hi i have same problem. any luck?

Comment: I still don't a solution.. let me know if you have any luck